# How to Partially removed JSON use intent putExtra on android

Tags: android, json

recently , I use `JSON parser`

In my server showing text this.

```
[{"name":"AAA", "age":"111"},
 {"name":"BBB", "age":"222"},
 {"name":"CCC", "age":"333"}]
```

and I try JSON parser this text.  show listview.

```
String strData = "";
.
.
.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            data = object.getString("name") + "." + object.getString("age");
            adapter.add(data);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

and this result in my phone.

```
AAA.111
-------
BBB.222
-------
CCC.333
```

Until right here
but I want when I list item button click data transport.

so I use `intent.putExtra`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         ListView listView =(ListView) parent;

         Intent intent = new Intent(this, anotherActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("information", adapter.getItem(position));
         startActivity(intent);
      }
 });
```

this is success data transport. 
but I don't want all data transport.

for example . I send only `age` data trasport.

In other words , showing my phone `name` data, `age` data.
     and transport another activity data.  only `name` data.

is it possible programmatically?

if you not understand. please advice for me.

thanks.

@update question

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     ListView listView =(ListView) parent;

     String data =adapter.getItem(position);
     String[] parts = data.split(".");
     String name = parts[0];
     Log.d(TAG, name);  // not showing log..   not work ?.. 
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, anotherActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("information", adapter.getItem(position));
     startActivity(intent);
  }
```

});

Comment: I really couldn't get what exactly your question is

Comment: @nikhil I'm sorry my explain very lack..     `strData = object.getString("name") +  "." +  object.getString("age");  adapter.add(StrData);`   this source showing my phone. age data, name data.  and I want  only name data send my another activity class.

Comment: refer answer by Julián Martínez. that will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this before declaring your intent

```
String data = adapter.getItem(position);    
String[] parts = data.split(".");
String name = parts[0];
```

and then:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, anotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("information", name);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I write `String data = adapter.getItem(position);      String[] parts = data.split("."); String name = parts[0];`  in setOnItemClickListener.  but not work..

Comment: @chohyunwook what do you mean by not work? What's the exact issue?

Comment: Replace `String data =adapter.getItem(position);` with `String data =listView.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Comment: Thanks @Prerak Sola, I was assuming adapter.getItem(position) worked.

Comment: sorry. I try @PrerakSola answer , but `Incompatible types,  required string, found object`

Comment: My bad, add `.toString()` in the end,

Comment: I check use `Log.d`    `data ===> AAA.111`  `parts ===>[Ljava.lang.String;@b96f467   `  `name ===> ` .. . :(